# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 (Multidimensional Associative Arrays)

Tags: php, forms, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Anyone know why I keep getting an error? I tried it many times and I can't figure it out.
What is wrong with my code?
The goal is to calculate distances between two cities based on the city names given by the user using a form input.

```
<form action="eudistance.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Start" placeholder="Start City...">
    <input type="text" name="End" placeholder="End City...">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

```
$Distances = array(
            "Berlin" => array("Berlin" => 0, "Moscow" => 1607.99, "Paris" => 876.96, "Prague" => 280.34, "Rome" => 1181.67),
            "Moscow" => array("Berlin" => 1607.99, "Moscow" => 0, "Paris" => 2484.92, "Prague" => 1664.04, "Rome" => 2374.26),
            "Paris" => array("Berlin" => 876.96, "Moscow" => 641.31, "Paris" => 0, "Prague" => 885.38, "Rome" => 1105.76),
            "Prague" => array("Berlin" => 280.34, "Moscow" => 1664.04, "Paris" => 885.38, "Prague" => 0, "Rome" => 922),
            "Rome" => array("Berlin" => 1181.67, "Moscow" => 2374.26, "Paris" => 1105.76, "Prague" => 922, "Rome" => 0)
);

if(isset($Distances)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($Distances); $i++) {
        for ($d = 0; $d < count($Distances[$i]); $d++) {
            if(($_POST['start'] == $Distances[$i]) && ($_POST['end'] == $Distances[$i][$d])) {
                print $Distances[$i] * $Distances[$i][$d];
            }   
        };
    };
} else {
    echo "Array does not exist";
}
```

Comment: It would be good to show the error you are getting, rather than expecting someone to enter in the code to test it.

Comment: Hi Patrick, the error was "Notice: Undefined offset: 0" + the file name. But I already got the issue fixed with the help of another person here. Thanks brother!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to access an associative array with numeric keys, which will not work. However your code can be written much more simply anyway by just indexing the `$Distances` array with `$_POST['start']` and `$_POST['end']`:

```
echo $Distances[$_POST['start']][$_POST['end']] ?? 'Unknown';
```

For example, if `$_POST = array('start' => 'Paris', 'end' => 'Berlin')` this gives

```
876.96
```

If it's possible that `$_POST['start']` or `$_POST['end']` might not be set, using this code will prevent warnings:

```
if (isset($_POST['start'], $_POST['end'], $Distances[$_POST['start']][$_POST['end']])) {
    echo $Distances[$_POST['start']][$_POST['end']];
}
else {
    echo "Unknown";
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gLuYe)

Comment: Hi Nick, thank your for your answer. I am trying to understand your answer; it might be advanced for me. Do i still keep the for loop? if so, how can i access it using your method?

Comment: @muse you don't need the `for` loop at all. Just replace the entire loop with the `echo`. See the demo at the link I provided.

Comment: Thanks again Nick. How can i take the user input as the name of the city? I tried using $_POST['start']  as you wrote it above, but somehow it is not working.

Comment: @muse your problem is that in your form the names are `Start` and `End`, so in your code you need to refer to `$_POST['Start']` and `$_POST['End']` instead, or change the names in the form to `start` and `end`